# Vue-router push undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, quasar

I used Quasar framework to design my UI. When I use a function to logout and push to another route using `vue-router` I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I use a vuex action method to logout and replace:

```
export const handleAuthStateChanged = ({ commit }, payload) => {
  firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // user is logged in
      let userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
      firebaseDB.ref("users/" + userId).once("value", function(snapshot) {
        let userDetails = snapshot.val();
        commit("USER_DETAILS", {
          name: userDetails.name,
          email: userDetails.email,
          online: userDetails.online,
          type: userDetails.type,
          userId: userId
        });
      });
      this.$router.push('');
    } else {
      // user is logged out
      commit("USER_DETAILS", {});
      this.$router.replace('chat');
    }
  });
};
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: The error is suggesting that `this.$router` is undefined. You're going to have to figure out why it never got the value you expect.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson  how can i do that. can you suggest some ways

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

- The `this` context issue already covered by @MisterCurtis's answer

  Normal functions have their own `this` context while es6 arrow functions inherit it.  Some [reading](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) about that.
- `this.$router` only makes sense if `this` is a component instance.  Vue inserts your `router` onto its instance prototype.  But this code is a Vuex action, not an instance method.

To use `vue-router` in an external module, like Vuex, or any other module, you can import it:

```
import router from '@/router'
```

And then use

```
router.push
```

instead of `this.$router.push`

An alternative would be to manage the auth result in the login component and use `this.$router` there.

Comment: i used this method. but it isn't push my route.

Comment: this is my code in github. https://github.com/kmihiranga/quasar_app

Answer (score 1):

Any new function will define its own `this` value. Inside your callback `this` is no longer pointing to the original Vue instance "this".

Try changing:

`firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { ...`

to an arrow function:

`firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { ...`

`this` will then properly refer to the original Vue instance where `$router` is defined.

Comment: i remake it like this but then shows me "Cannot read property '$router' of undefined" this error

Comment: I realize now you're not in context of Vue since the method is a Vuex action. @Dan's answer is correct, you'll either have to import your Vue instance, or the Router instance. Be conscious of the possibility for circular dependancies do develop when bringing importing the main Vue or Router instances.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for try to fix my issue. i fixed it using without using arrow functions in vuex actions.

```
export const handleAuthStateChanged = function ({ commit }, payload) {
...
```